# Hash Table - Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)

Tags: c++, hashtable, valgrind

I am coding a HashTable using a Doubly Linked list for one of my classes, but I am running into an error when I run valgrind. It says: Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s). When I run --track-origins=yes, it says:

```
==11453== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==11453==    at 0x402904: LinkedList<std::string>::itemExists(std::string const&) (LinkedList.h:89)
==11453==    by 0x401FE6: HashSet<std::string>::find(std::string const&) (HashSet.h:85)
==11453==    by 0x401E42: HashSet<std::string>::add(std::string const&) (HashSet.h:39)
==11453==    by 0x4019D7: insert(std::string, std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::string, HashSet<std::string>&) (main.cpp:64)
==11453==    by 0x4015B1: main (main.cpp:34)
==11453==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==11453==    at 0x4C2B800: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==11453==    by 0x4024D8: HashSet<std::string>::rehash() (HashSet.h:131)
==11453==    by 0x401E69: HashSet<std::string>::add(std::string const&) (HashSet.h:45)
==11453==    by 0x4019D7: insert(std::string, std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::string, HashSet<std::string>&) (main.cpp:64)
==11453==    by 0x4015B1: main (main.cpp:34)
```

So I think the problem is in my rehash function, but I can't figure out where it is. Could you guys help me out? Here is my rehash function:

```
void rehash()
{
    int old_size = tableSize;
    if (tableSize == itemsStored) {
        tableSize = tableSize * 2 + 1;
    }

    else if (itemsStored <= tableSize/2) {
        tableSize = tableSize / 2;
    }
        LinkedList<string>* newTable = new LinkedList<string>[tableSize];    -------> line 131
        for (int i = 0; i < old_size; ++i)
        {
            int table_size = 0;
            table_size = table[i].getSize();
            if(table_size != 0) {
                for (int j = 0; j < table_size; ++j) {
                        unsigned index = hashFunction(table[i].getItem(j)) % tableSize;
                        newTable[index].insert(newTable[index].getSize(), table->getItem(i));

                }
            }
        }
        LinkedList<string>* temp = table;
        table = newTable;
        delete [] temp;

}
```

And this is my constructor for the Hash Set:

```
HashSet()
{
    int tableSize = 0;
    table = new LinkedList<string>[tableSize];
}
```

This is my constructor for the LinkedList:

```
LinkedList()
{
    size = 0;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: The problem could equally well exist in the `insert` code-path.  Why don't you step through with a debugger to see what's going on?

Comment: Can you mark line 131?

Comment: And: Are all members of a linked list initialised in its constructors?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth , thank you so much for answering. So, the problem is that my debugger won't complain about it. It runs perfectly fine, valgrind is the one that accuses the issue, and in order for me to get full credit for this assignment, valgrind must be happy. I will check the insert code again, though.

Comment: @DanielJour, thank you for your help! I edited the question, marking line 131 and showing my constructors.

Comment: You may need to add`()` to your table allocation.

Comment: Glad the issue got solved. Did you check the tableSize init as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to take a lucky guess here: your `LinkedList` contains a `head` pointer and your `itemExists` function loads that pointer before checking if the `size` field is greater than zero.

Something like

```
Node* node = head;
for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    if (node->hash == ...)
    ...
    node = node->next;
}
```

Looks innocent because the pointer isn't dereferenced if `size == 0`, but reading an uninitialized pointer is UB in itself.

Answer (score 0):

Oh my, that's hard to spot. If it isn't what @PaulGroke already suggested, then there's also a potential problem here:

```
HashSet()
{
    /* */int/* */ tableSize = 0; // HERE!
    table = new LinkedList<string>[tableSize];
}
```

From your `rehash` member function I'd guess that your hash set class has a member named `tableSize`. The above constructor has a local variable with the same name that *shadows* this member. As consequence, the member field is never initialised, and you have undefined behaviour. Removing the marked `int` should solve this.

In general, you should use the initialiser list to write your constructors:

```
HashSet()
 : tableSize(0), 
   table(new LinkedList<string>[tableSize]); {
}
```

Though it's debatable whether this should be done for allocations as I did above, but then you normally shouldn't use raw `new` or `new []` in code at all, better `std::shared_pointer`/`std::unique_pointer` or `std::vector`.